# max value in Python

Tags: python, numpy, max, min

I have a python array that contains a list of events, and the corresponding values of flood at certain gauges.  It is read in like this:

```
tmp = np.fromfile( Max_File, sep=' ')
nGauges = int(tmp[0]); nEvents = (tmp.size-1)/nGauges;
Max = np.reshape(tmp[1::],[ nEvents, nGauges ])
```

What I would like to do now is, instead of having 1000 events, and the corresponding 1000 flood gauge recordings that go with them, I want the 1000 events, and the MAXIMUM flood value for that event.

So the result might look like this:

```
1, 3.4  
2, 4.5  
3, 1.2  
4, 3.2
```

Right now the events are simply ordered from 1 to 1000.  I will rename with with a separate input file when I need to.

I know that I somehow need to use the MAX() function, but I have been playing around with this so much and cannot see to get it to work!

Thanks,
Kimberly

Comment: Can you post a couple example lines of input from that file so we can see how it is structured/formatted? Or rather, now that you have reshaped your data, what do a few lines of that array look like?

Comment: While this particular problem is easily handled in pure numpy, most of the time data processing tasks are more straightforward in [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org).  If you can imagine needing a groupby operation, or wanting to store mixed-type data (strings as well as floats), then it's definitely worth checking `pandas` out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an assumption about what your reshaped Numpy array looks like. Here's an example, assuming I got the structure correct:

```
# In each row 1st element is the event, the rest are gage values
l = [[1, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4],
     [2, 5.4, 3.2, 4.2, 1.1],
     [3, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]

for line in l:
    print line[0],  max(line[1::])
```

Result

```
1 4.4
2 5.4
3 3.0
```

Similarly, using a list comp

```
[(i[0], max(i[1::])) for i in l]
```

Result

```
[(1, 4.4), (2, 5.4), (3, 3.0)]
```

Comment: Using the normal `max` function when you already have `numpy` arrays available is not the most efficient way.

Answer (score 4):

You want to find the maximum value of the 1000x1000 `ndarray` along the `ngauges` axis (1):

```
>>> a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> a.max(axis = 1)
array([ 4,  9, 14, 19, 24])
>>> a.max(axis = 1).reshape(5,1)
array([[ 4],
       [ 9],
       [14],
       [19],
       [24]])
>>> np.array([(n, m) for n, m in enumerate(a.max(axis=1))])
array([[ 0,  4],
       [ 1,  9],
       [ 2, 14],
       [ 3, 19],
       [ 4, 24]])
>>>
```

or using numpy.insert():

```
>>> np.insert(a.max(axis=1).reshape(5,1),0, values = range(1, len(a)+1), axis = 1)
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 2,  9],
       [ 3, 14],
       [ 4, 19],
       [ 5, 24]])
>>>
```